# Error in creating a drop down list under <li></li> in angular 7

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to build a list in Angular and my scenario is when I click on HELP(link) the dropdown list should be displayed where each one is again a link that navigates to the respective page.

I tried below code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <div id="navbar-color">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active" ngbDropdown>
          <a 
            class="nav-link" 
            style="cursor: pointer" 
            ngbDropdownToggle 
            id="navbarDropdown1" 
            role="button">
            Help
          </a>
          <div 
            ngbDropdownMenu 
            aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1" 
            class="dropdown-menu">
            <a 
              ngbDropdownItem 
              href="#" 
              (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
              Guides & FAQS
            </a>
            <a 
              ngbDropdownItem 
              href="#" 
              (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
              Contact Us 
            </a>
            <a 
              ngbDropdownItem 
              href="#" 
              (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
              Feedback
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

But when I click on the Help link nothing is working, the drop is not displayed.

Not sure what is missing ever after debugging in the browser. Referred the below link

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples

Please let me know if I'm missing anything or if there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Create and provide a demo link what you have tried and let us know

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren, I tried to debug in browser console. this is not just copy-pasted code  i used the link as reference "https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples".
my intention was to seek some help i apologize if misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `href`s in your template and it's value is `#`. Plus you're also calling `$event.preventDefault()` on your button click which is not going to propagate the event.

Since you're using Angular, I'd take the liberty to assume that you're implementing this for a SPA. And since that's the case, you might have a route config in place that might look something like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: "list", component: ListComponent },
  { path: "guide-faq", component: GuidesAndFaqsComponent },
  { path: "contact-us", component: ContactUsComponent },
  { path: "feedback", component: FeedbackComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/list', pathMatch: 'full' }
])
```

That being said, you can simply use `routerLink` and navigate the user accordingly on it's click.

Here, give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent {

  list = new Array(5).fill(4).map((item, index) => index + 1);

}
```

And in your template:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of list">
        <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
            <button 
        class="btn btn-outline-primary" 
        id="dropdownBasic1" 
        ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown {{ item }}</button>
            <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
                <button ngbDropdownItem routerLink="/guide-faq">Guides & FAQS</button>
                <button ngbDropdownItem routerLink="/contact-us">Contact Us</button>
                <button ngbDropdownItem routerLink="/feedback">Feedback</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-dropdown-in-a-list?file=app/list/list.component.html) for your ref.